# How to compare characters in C#

Tags: c#, char, compare

I'm trying to compare two characters in C#. The "==" operator does not work for strings, you have to use the .Equals() method. In the following code example I want to read each character in the input string, and output another string without spaces.

```
    string inputName, outputName = null;
    // read input name from file
    foreach (char indexChar in inputName)
    {
       if (!indexChar.Equals(" "))
          outputName += indexChar;
    }
```

This does not work, the comparison always equals false, even when the input name has embedded spaces. I also tried using the overload method Equals(string, string), which did not work either. I'm assuming C# treats char variables as a string of length 1. Microsoft's documentation doesn't seem to mention comparing characters. Does anyone have a better method for comparing characters in a string?

Comment: what makes you think the `==` operator doesn't work? it'll work with `' '`

Comment: Why not just to use Replace method as `var outputName = inputName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);`?

Answer (score 6):

`" "` is a `string` of length one; a `char` and a `string` never match; you want `' '`, the space *character*:

```cs
if (indexChar != ' ')
```

However, if you're just trying to remove all spaces, it is probably easier to just do:

```cs
var outputName = inputName.Replace(" ", "");
```

This avoids allocating lots of intermediate strings.

Note also that the space character isn't the only whitespace character in unicode. If you need to deal with all whitespace characters, a regex may be a better option:

```cs
var outputName = Regex.Replace(inputName, @"\s", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .CompareTo(char) to compare characters.
Example :

```
if('Z'.CompareTo('Z') == 0)
   Console.WriteLine("Same character !");
```

Comment: Well you already mentioned it in your answer haha, this is just another way to compare characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great suggestions. inputName.CompareTo(" ") is not the way to go for this example, you would still have to have a loop. I ended up using:

`var outputName = Regex.Replace(inputName, @"\s", "")`
which works, and it's only one line of code!